What are the goals and nature of the Agarthans?
In Joko Anwar's Nightmares and Daydreams, there is an organization of creatures that come from a dimension called Agartha and that look like (or disguise themselves as) humans with black eyes and supernatural abilities.
We see a group of them that seem to

be dedicated to eating the body parts of particularly talented people and another one that keeps a woman and her child (their child?) imprisoned and otherwise acts mainly like a mundane domestic abuser, and something that is probably the same and that mentally controls people in "The Other Side."


The creatures from "Old House" also seem to have some connection to Agartha, since they are said to come "from below" and their followers use the triangle symbol, but they only seem interested in helping transfer vitality to elderly people and don't look much like humans. Also, since the orphan Syafin is shown during the narration about the creatures from Agartha in the final episode, it seems to also be implied that he is one of them, though his powers seem much greater and he may not even be actively malicious.

Overall, the appearances, powers and actions of all these individuals seem fairly varied. As such, what are the nature and goals of the Agarthans?
